# Unlock Keychain items using Yubikey

Tags: security, keychain, smart-card

I have [setup my Yubikey as a smart card](https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016649059) so I can login with the key and its PIN code. After logging in with the Yubikey, the login keychain is unlocked. However, opening a keychain item en trying to show a password, Keychain Access asks for my login password instead of my PIN. Applications trying to access the keychain requiring me to authenticate also ask for my login password instead of the Yubikey PIN.

Is it possible to convince Keychain Access to allow me to authenticate with the Yubikey and PIN code instead?

Comment: facing the same problem, have you managed to solve it somehow?